# Let $\displaystyle f \colon \Bbb C\setminus \{3i\} \to \Bbb C$ be defined by..

Tags: complex-analysis

I am stuck on the following problem:

> Let $\displaystyle f \colon \Bbb C\setminus \{3i\} \to \Bbb C$ be defined by $$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{iz+3}.$$ Then verify whether the following statement is TRUE or FALSE?
>
> All the fixed points of $f$ are in the region $\{z \in \Bbb C: \Im(z)>0\}$

MY ATTEMPT: For fixed points of $f$, set $$f(z)=z \implies i(1+z^2)+2z=0 \tag{1}.$$ Now, putting $z=x+iy$ in $(1)$ gives $i\{1+x^2-y^2+2y\}-2xy+2x=0$. Now, comparing real and imaginary part from both sides gives $y=1>0$. So, the above statement should be true but the answer key says that it is false. I do not know where I went wrong. Can someone explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{z-i}{iz+3}=z\iff iz^2+2z+i=0\implies\text{the discriminant is}\;\;\Delta=4+4=8\implies$$

$$z_{1,2}=\frac{-2\pm2\sqrt2}{2i}=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt2}{i}=(1\pm\sqrt2)i$$

and the claim is false.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the imaginary parts from both sides gives you $x(y - 1) = 0$. So either $y = 1$ or $x = 0$. It turns out that $y = 1$ doesn't give you solutions, but $x = 0$ does. To see this, just solve the quadratic equation $iz^2 + 2z + i = 0$.